# how to check network usage?

Tags: networking

As I was checking (on the gnome system monitor that comes with 13.10) to see why [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org) was lagging on my computer without a mouse and keyboard I saw a high total amount of data transmitted.

I've been seeing this for the last 3 days now and I was wondering if there is a way to monitor the network usage of each process individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nethogs I think.

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

then run

```
sudo nethogs $device
```

or if you use wlan, then

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

Also check out `iftop` and `netstat` and `vnstat`. All are very important programs for network monitoring, but all have a different purpose.

`nethogs` shows current network usage by processes (program names)

`iftop` shows current network usage by connections (IPs/hosts)

`netstat` shows the connections by state (this doesn't show bandwith usage, but shows everything else about a connection.)

`vnstat` is a traffic monitor, e.g for keeping yourself in your data plan or later analysis.

Just install them, and look in their manuals.